Expand Selection Mask in Geometry Nodes
I'm trying to create a mask that will give me random rectangles (not squares) on a surface that I can adjust the size of and I'm have a really hard time making a mask for it. 
This is what I'm trying to do, with red and blue being controlled independently from each other.
This is just selecting faces using a random value. Sticking it into a blur attribute node expands it in all directions. Everything I've tried in order to control the expansion has failed. I've tried some really silly setups that didn't work and I'm going insane. 
One of the biggest problems is that the geometry I'm using the mask on is curvy, so anything using position becomes difficult.
Any advice would be really appreciated. I've spent the past two days on this problem and I feel really dumb. Thank you.
Edit for Clarification: The initial selection (in white) I'm trying to expand on the X and/or Z axes. Only that initial white selection is random. The expansion of the mask would be controlled. It's important that I'm selecting faces as well.
Edit 2 For More Clarification: Again sorry for not being clear. The rule would be to expand in a chosen direction by a variable of my choosing. For example I want to expand on the X axes in both directions from the initial random selection (the white faces) by one face (red squares. 
Then I would want to be able to expand the selection up on the z axes by one space from that selection (blue squares)
I hope that makes more sense. I'm not really sure how to be more clear than that.

Do you want to keep a « grid » effect (i.e. rectangles made of squares) ? Or are you looking for random distributions, just keeping horizontal and vertical sides ?

...and additionally, if you do not want to keep a grid but instead have random rectangles (which I assume otherwise it would be complicated to make them random in both, horizontal and vertical direction), I guess they should not overlap or is it okay if they do? It would have been good if you showed how you want it to look.

Sorry here's a bit more information for clarity. Basically from the initial selection (in white) I'm trying to expand the selection on the X and/or Z axes. Only that initial white selection is random. The expansion of the mask would be controlled. Added image for clarification. It's important that I'm selecting faces as well.

Maybe I'm the slowest brain here but I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What is the rule for your expansion, any cell should expand on all 4 directions by one cell ? Is there only one step of that, or multiple repeating steps ? Why are the red rectangles of your last image not square ? I'm sure it's clear for you, but I have too little understanding to even try to answer you.

OK I made another edit. Sorry If I haven't been very clear.
